# Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, nativescript

I am building an native android Wallpaper app using vue-cli. i am trying to make an image downloader using nativescript-downloader plugin of nativescript.
After installing nativescript-downloader using npm install --save nativescript-downloader when I trying to  debug using npm run debug:android  getting this Error.Error log is given below.

wallpaper@1.0.0 debug:android /home/darahat/Desktop/Wallpaper
npm run debug -- --env.android

wallpaper@1.0.0 debug /home/darahat/Desktop/Wallpaper
webpack --watch --env.tnsAction debug "--env.android"

info: Copying NativeScript plugins to template dependencies...
info: Preparing NativeScript application from template...
npm WARN wallpaper@ No repository field.

info: Bundling application for android...

Webpack is watching the files…

Executing post-build scripts

> info: Debugging NativeScript application...
>   Searching for devices...
>   Preparing project...
>   Project successfully prepared (Android)
>   Building project...
>   Gradle build...
>            + applying user-defined configuration from /home/darahat/Desktop/Wallpaper/dist/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
>   Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
>   Configuration 'debugCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'debugImplementation' instead.
>            + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: /home/darahat/Desktop/Wallpaper/dist/node_modules/nativescript-downloader/platforms/android/nativescript_downloader.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: /home/darahat/Desktop/Wallpaper/dist/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar
>
> Unable to apply changes on device: 0123456789ABCDEF. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please read this carefully before asking your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1. In the command line use the command **cd** to move inside the Android folder of your project.
2. Go to [Gradle intallation guide on their website](https://gradle.org/install/) and run the command listed below while inside the android folder on your command line
   [image: Gradle wrapper command]

3. After copying, pasting and running the command highlighted in the picture you should be all set

**Enjoy and have a nice day**